# IIS 7 and Entity Framework connection string

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am using Entity Framework in ASP.Net project. It works fine in development server. But it throws exceptions in IIS 7. I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise as the backend.

```
Entity Framework Connection String in the web.config follows
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GIRI-PC\GIRISQL2008;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The error I get in iis 7 is:

```
      System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at _Default.btn_submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.  Sounds like you need to properly configure either; your app pool to use an account that has access to the database, create a new app pool with an account that has access to the database, or allow the DefaultAppPool identity to access the database.

The Database Server the website is trying to access is `GIRI-PC\GIRISQL2008`.  If that is not correct you'll need to; update your `web.config` to point to the correct Sql Server (and instance) or create `web.config` transformations (preferred) to keep your development settings and deployment settings (dev, test, stage, prod) seperated.

Answer (score 1):

More clearly: SQL Server client could make contact with the specified instance of SQL Server ("GIRI-PC\GIRISQL2008").

This could be:

- Lack of a common protocol
- Need to specify a different TCP port for IP
- Server instance is not listening on the network port your connection is using
- Host name could not be resolved (or is wrong)
- Instance name is wrong